# Shiro session timeout shows an error: There is no session with id using Struts2

Tags: java, session, shiro

I have this codes using Shiro:

LoginAction.java:

```
@Action(value = "loginUser", results = { @Result(name = "error", type = "tiles", location = "error") })
public String loginRegisterUser() {

    String retStr = null;

    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(loginUser.getUserName(),loginUser.getUserPassword());
    token.setRememberMe(true);

    try {           

        Session session = currentUser.getSession();

        session.setAttribute("USERID", loginUser.getUserName());
        session.setAttribute("SESSIONID", session.getId());

        System.out.println("USERID: " + session.getAttribute("USERID"));
        System.out.println("SESSIONID: " + session.getAttribute("SESSIONID"));

        // session.setAttribute("LOGINUSER", loginUser); //TODO by Carmela: Add Resource Details
        sessionAttributes.put("USERID", session.getAttribute("USERID"));
        sessionAttributes.put("SESSIONID", session.getAttribute("SESSIONID"));

        currentUser.login(token);

        session.stop();
        currentUser.getSession(true);

        if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
            session = currentUser.getSession(false);
            session.touch();

            session.setAttribute("USERID", sessionAttributes.get("USERID"));
            session.setAttribute("SESSIONID", sessionAttributes.get("SESSIONID"));

            System.out.println("user is authenticated!!!!!");
            System.out.println("isAuthenticated USERID: " + session.getAttribute("USERID"));
            System.out.println("isAuthenticated SESSIONID: " + session.getAttribute("SESSIONID"));

            session.setTimeout(30000);

            retStr = "loginUserSuccess";
        }
    } catch (ExpiredSessionException e) {
        System.out.println("LoginAction ExpiredSessionException");
    } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
        addActionError("Unknown account.");
        retStr = "loginUserLogin";
        uae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException iae) {
        addActionError("Incorrect Username and Password.");
        retStr = "loginUserLogin";
        iae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LockedAccountException lae) {
        addActionError("Your account has been locked.");
        retStr = "loginUserLogin";
        lae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
        addActionError("Enter Valid Username or Password");
        retStr = "loginUserLogin";
        ae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        addActionError("Error!");
        retStr = "loginUserLogin";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return retStr;
}
```

shiro.ini:

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp
ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://10.62.24.210:10389
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername = something
ldapRealm.contextFactory.systemPassword = password
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = simple
ldapRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = false
```

Whenever my session timesout after 30 seconds and hit the same url, it shows me the
    error:

```
Messages: Session with id [6944e751-96bd-49ad-aab9-66ed42da4c9c] has expired. Last 
access time: 2/19/14 6:00 PM. Current time: 2/19/14 6:03PM. Session timeout is set to  
30 seconds (0 minutes) 
File: org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/SimpleSession.java
```

When I hit again the same url, it shows me this message:

```
Messages: There is no session with id [6944e751-96bd-49ad-aab9-66ed42da4c9c] 
File: org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/eis/AbstractSessionDAO.java
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.